# How can I add an Ubuntu flavor?

Tags: custom-distributions

I know that this is a dumb question, but I don't really know much in this area. I created a new lightweight flavor for Ubuntu. How can it get recognized as an Ubuntu based distro. Is their any final authority on this. I just need a way to release my distro. Can someone tell me?

Comment: The final say is the (official) Ubuntu wiki pages, but a number of people have blogged and/or talked about it on podcasts. Martin Wimpress (now head of Ubuntu Desktop, but he worked elsewhere back then) spoke numerous times about the creation of Ubuntu MATE firstly, then it's move to an official flavor as one example. There are a number of unofficial *remixes* that have very recently talked & are going through the processes to become official flavors (some are due/hope to become official *flavors* next year), and they are very recent (progress is still occurring; read those blogs etc)

Comment: Have you started by putting it up somewhere for download? One of the prerequisites seems to be a fan base/following. You'll need those to have any hope of being an official flavor.